# Getting Out of memory error while comparing two large xml files

Tags: java, xmlunit

I am trying to compare two large XML files uisng XMLUNIT, but I am getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/abc/a.xml");

    FileReader file1 = new FileReader("C:/abc/b.xml");
    assertXMLEquals(file, file1);
}


public static void assertXMLEquals(FileReader expectedXML, FileReader actualXML) throws Exception {

        DetailedDiff difference = null;
        try {
            // Checks each Node
            difference = new DetailedDiff(XMLUnit.compareXML(expectedXML, actualXML));
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        if (!difference.similar()) {
            List<Difference> AllDifferences = difference.getAllDifferences();
            System.out.println("Xml comparison failed because of follwoing error/s : \n"+AllDifferences);
        }
    }
```

**Solution - I have added "-Xms2048M -Xmx2048M" as arguments in Eclipse Run configurations.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent used xmlunit. But looking at the xmlunit documentation, it looks like you can use streams as the input.

eg:
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathname))

Using streams will not load whole file at once to memory.

But for the to get a OutOfMemoryError exception the files should be very large. You can also increase the maximum heap size for the application at startup.

eg: Increasing min heap size (xms) and max heap size (xmx) to 2GB.

java -Xms2048mm -Xmx2048m

Comment: I have added "-Xms2048M -Xmx2048M" as arguments in Eclipse Run configurations.It worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using SAX Parser ?
It will solve your problem, as it does not require loading the whole file into memory to process it.

btw whats the size of your files ?

Comment: size of my file is 55MB

Comment: Can you please provide me the example of SAX parser or any link?

Comment: You can check websites like tutorialspoint or journaldev. The sample code is readily available there. e.g. https://www.journaldev.com/1198/java-sax-parser-example

Let me know if you find any difficulty using this.